# Flutter app for IOS watch and Android watch

Tags: flutter, watch, audio-player, android-auto, carplay

I have to make one book-reading app that includes a music player.  for both mobile and tablet (iPhone and iPad).

client requirements are

> 1. control the music player from the smart-watch. so how can I do it?
>    -> did i need to make separate app for i-watch?
>    -> how can i configure for android app for simple watch? ( company like - boat,samsung,fire-boalt,mi )?

founded this packages : [watch_connectivity: ^0.1.3](https://pub.dev/packages/watch_connectivity) , [wear](https://pub.dev/packages/wear) ,

> 2. Can i control music from android auto and apple car play?
>    -> i found package for apple car pay - [carplay](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_carplay)
>    -> but can i found for anrodi auto?

Answer (score 0):

To control music you may need some app
With flutter you cannot make an app for apple watch like you do for other OSs,
So either you develop Apple watch App using Xcode and use Wear plugin for developing  app for wear OS by google.
Then you can communicate using Bluetooth or other things.

Comment: how to communicate with Bluetooth in flutter

Comment: I cannot tell how but surely there must be the mechanism for this, this must include handshaking or something then you can communicate by sending instructions 
I googled this , maybe helpful to you.
https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-for-bluetooth-devices-5594f105b146